# Mysql trigger creation throwing error with NEW.ref being undefined

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to track universal IDs using an OBJECTS table, which contains the auto incrementing id field to be used in other tables. When a unique constraint is hit in the other tables, the OBJECTS table still consumes an id. Im trying to stop that with an if exists function on the before_insert trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER places_BINS BEFORE INSERT ON places FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM places WHERE ref = NEW.ref)) THEN
SET NEW.id = NULL;
ELSE
INSERT INTO objects (object_type) VALUES ('place');
SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I get an error when trying to create the trigger:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ref' in 'NEW'
```

Is my understanding of NEW incorrect? I think NEW should have any fields that may interact with the table.

'ref' is a field in the table with a Unique constraint.

Comment: What happens if you assign NEW.ref to a temporary variable & use that variable in the query?

Comment: Can you show table schemas for both tables?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a mis-spelling. ref was not defined it turns out! Thanks for your help.

Incase anyone comes across this, the trigger is how i have emulated "sequences" in oracleDB with mysql. The trigger creates a record in the shared auto-incrementing table upon insert, if the record does not already exist. This works with ON DUPLICATE function in the insert statement to avoid consuming IDs for failed insert attempts. AS places.id has a not null constraint, records would fail  to insert and the error can be caught.

Thanks all!